# Loading Module in AngularJS Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS. Currently, I'm trying to load a third-party module in my service. Specifically, I'm trying to load `angular-moment`. My service is defined like this:

```
myApp.factory('myService', ['angularMoment', function(angularMoment) {
  return {
    getLocale: function() {
      return angularMoment.locale();
    }
  }
}]);
```

If I replace return `angularMoment.locale()` with `return 'someLocale';` my code runs. However, as soon as I reference `angularMoment`, I get errors. I know it has something to do with the fact that I'm not loading the module correctly. However, I do not know what I'm doing wrong. I just see this error when I run my unit tests:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$injector/unpr?p0=angularMomentProvider%20%3C-%20angularMoment%20%3C-myService (line 36) (1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you following everything in the Usage at https://github.com/urish/angular-moment mainly the sequence of <script> tags ?

Comment: Your angularMoment js file needs to be loaded before your application js file. Meaning angularMoment needs to be defined before it is injected into your factory. Make sure your files are loading in correct order.

Comment: There is no service named `angularMoment`, and also there is no `.locale()` method. May be it is a different library from the one that @bhantol mentioned?

Comment: I do not actually have a web page. I'm building some AngularJS services. I'm getting this error in my Jasmne tests.

Comment: Having the same issue, any conclusion on this?

Answer (score 2):

Try 'moment' instead of angularMoment in the service/factor injector. This will give you the object from MomentJS

```
myApp.factory('myService', ['moment', function(moment) {
  return {
    getLocale: function() {
      return moment.locale();
    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the `angularMoment` module when declaring your module. Otherwise it won't get loaded. That is what causes the `$injector:unpr` error. So you need something like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["angularMoment"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound basic, but you are referencing the .js files in your html code, right?

Comment: I'm referencng the .js files in my Jasmine task. I'm running the code via Grunt.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularMoment']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $log, moment) {
      var now = moment();
      $log.info(now.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));
});
```